# Cannot update local variable

Tags: javascript

Have been trying to update a local variable (which is an array) via add/remove functions. I was able to add items using add function which also updated my local array but when I tried to remove the same using my code, it still returns my old array without modifications.
However, if I try to use pop() for removing an element, everything seems to work fine.

1. I know that filter from my remove function is returning the modified array but it's not getting updated in my array named `mainArr`.
2. Why is the array getting updated when I replace remove functionality with `mainArr.pop()` but not with my code.
3. The code also seems to work if I replace the assignment operator from my remove function to `this.mainArr = //return value from the filter`.

My remove function seems to be creating a new local variable with the same name `mainArr` due to which it is not updating my actual `mainArr`. Why is it doing so? Isn't it a concept of closures that my inner function can access global variables? What am I missing here?

```js
function test() {
  let mainArr = [];

  function add(func) {
    mainArr.push(func);
  }

  function remove(num) {
    mainArr = mainArr.filter(item => item !== num)
  }

   

 return {
    mainArr,
    add,
    remove
    }
   }

let val = test()

val.mainArr // returns []
val.add(3)
val.add(5)
val.mainArr //returns [3, 5]

val.remove(3)
console.log(val.mainArr) // still returns [3, 5]. Why?
```

Comment: You're reassigning to the local variable.  That won't update the other reference, `mainArr`.

Comment: `function remove(num) {
    const updated = mainArr.filter(item => item !== num); mainArr.length = 0; mainArr.push.apply(mainArr, updated);
  }`

Comment: thanks @epascarello, I get it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mainArr.push(func);` **mutates** the array.

`mainArr.filter(item => item !== num)` creates a **new** array.

`let mainArr = [];` is a variable which holds your original array. Later on, you assign the filtered version to the variable.

`return { mainArr, add, remove }` returns the value of `mainArr` which (at the time) is the original array. When you  later change the value of the `mainArr` variable, the previously returned value is **still** the original array (no time travel is performed!).

---

Create the object upfront, and then always modify properties of that object. Don't create it from variables which later have their values changed.

```js
function test() {

  function add(func) {
    data.mainArr.push(func);
  }

  function remove(num) {
    data.mainArr = data.mainArr.filter(item => item !== num)
  }

  const data = {
    mainArr: [],
    add,
    remove
  };

  return data;
}

let val = test()

console.log(val.mainArr);
val.add(3)
val.add(5)
console.log(val.mainArr)

val.remove(3)
console.log(val.mainArr)
```

In modern JS, this sort of thing is generally done with a class rather than a factory though.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.mainArr = [];
  }
  add(value) {
    this.mainArr.push(value);
  }
  remove(value) {
    this.mainArr = this.mainArr.filter(item => item !== value)
  }
}
let val = new Test()

console.log(val.mainArr);
val.add(3)
val.add(5)
console.log(val.mainArr)

val.remove(3)
console.log(val.mainArr)
```